# PAL Dreamcast game which still can be played online (on official server)?

Tags: game

*(See the [meta-discussion](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/51/60) if asking for game recommendations should be on-topic.)*

I’m looking for an online multiplayer [Dreamcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcast) game whose official game server is still online.

Requirements:

- Official game server, not a fan/private server.
- No subscription fee.
- It needs to run on a [PAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL) Dreamcast.
- The game (content/interface) needs to be available in **English**.
- It needs to have a **chat** system. Not only for private messages, but a multi-user chat.

I’d *prefer* a game where all online players can chat together at the same time (e.g., in a lobby), instead of a session-based game where you can only chat with those few people you are currently playing with. Of course, if there were a game that even allows all players to play together at the same time, this would even be better.

I don’t care about the game genre/setting or gameplay.

Comment: I really can't see the point of this question: what good is asking for a game without even mentioning a genre?

Comment: @Gilles: When I’m joining a [LAN party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAN_party), I don’t care about genre either. It’s playing *together* what is fun, no matter which game. -- And in this question’s case I’m not so much interested in playing but in chatting with other users still playing with their Dreamcast, but that shouldn’t make a difference. I could have asked instead for "**an instant messaging multi-user protocol+chat client running on Dreamcast natively and whose provider’s servers are still online, that comes with some (mini-)games**. But it would (should) still be a game, so ….

Comment: This question is looking for a specific type of software recommendation, within a pool of very few possible answers. The good asking such a question as-is, is that it might prevent the possible software recommendation list from reaching 0. Also, genres are somewhat ill-defined, even in the videogame dev scene. Some people like movies because of the actors, some because of the genre, some because of the topics, and even others because of where it was made.